# Get-AzAccessToken keeps returning the same Token by targeting a different tenant

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I have a PowerShell Azure Function that is secured with AAD. In my script I get the id token with the following command:

```
$assertion = $Request.Headers['x-ms-token-aad-id-token']
```

I use this assertion in order to get another token to use the Azure Service Management Api with the OBO Flow. Below is the code used:

```
$contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
$body = @{
    grant_type          = $grantType
    client_id           = $clientId
    client_secret       = $clientSecret
    scope               = $scope
    requested_token_use = $requestedTokenUse
    assertion           = $assertion
}

$oboResponse = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e005f490-xxxx-4816-xxxx-b0ed7fa9xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Method 'POST' -body $body -ContentType $contentType
$accessToken = $oboResponse.access_token
```

Then I use this token to connect to azure with the Connect-AzAccount command. So far, everything is good well and the connection to Azure is working fine.

In my script, I try to have different tokens to connect to other tenants to which I belong. Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. Indeed the command returns the same token for different tenants. In fact, the produced token by the command "Get-AzAccessToken -TenantId $tenant.Id" is always equal to the token produced by the OBO flow.

Below is my PowerShell Azure function. I commented the part where I have a the issue.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$accountId = $Request.Headers['x-ms-client-principal-name']
$grantType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
$clientId = "xxxx"
$clientSecret = "xxxx"
$scope = "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"
$requestedTokenUse = "on_behalf_of"
$assertion = $Request.Headers['x-ms-token-aad-id-token']

$contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
$body = @{
    grant_type          = $grantType
    client_id           = $clientId
    client_secret       = $clientSecret
    scope               = $scope
    requested_token_use = $requestedTokenUse
    assertion           = $assertion
}

$oboResponse = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e005f490-xxxx-4816-xxxx-b0ed7fa9xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Method 'POST' -body $body -ContentType $contentType
$accessToken = $oboResponse.access_token

Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken $accessToken -AccountId $accountId
$allTenants = Get-AzTenant

foreach ($tenant in $allTenants) {
    # Here I get the same access token for different tenants. 
    # The token is always equal to the token produced by the OBO flow.
    $accessToken_ = Get-AzAccessToken -TenantId $tenant.Id
    ....
    ....
}
...
...
```

I don't understand why the token produced by the OBO flow is always equal to the token produced by Get-AzAccessToken. I hope I have described my problem correctly, thank you for your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to your `Invoke-RestMethod` call using a static tenant ID/GUID:

```
$oboResponse = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e005f490-xxxx-4816-xxxx-b0ed7fa9xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Method 'POST' -body $body -ContentType $contentType
```

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{**tenant**}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```